# Writing a C# PowerShell cmdlet - how to output debug logging to TeamCity caller

Tags: c#, powershell, teamcity, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a PowerShell cmdlet in C#, and I need to add some diagnostic logging to the script so that I can evaluate the behavior through TeamCity. Having experimented with WriteVerbose with the `-Verbose` flag enabled for the function, nothing was logged to TeamCity.

What is the equivalent of [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) for a cmdlet?

What is the difference between the following cmdlets:

- WriteCommandDetail
- WriteProgress
- WriteVerbose
- WriteDebug
- WriteWarning
- WriteError
- WriteObject

Comment: Side note: I just read that $VerbosePreference is by default set to SilentlyContinue, to show Verbose logging, you need to set this variable to at least Continue. Calling -Verbose on the cmdlet was insufficient, however setting this in the parent PS script may help:
$Global:VerbosePreference="Continue"
*Test in progress*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else encounters this issue, this is what I learnt: PowerShell supports many different output streams.

The one that TeamCity is after however is none of the above, [C#] Console.WriteLine is sufficient to log to the TeamCity trace log.

To answer my previous question:

WriteError is used for returning exceptions properly (this works well, albeit a little convoluted, just using C# throw will crash PowerShell when debugging a cmdlet).

WriteObject is used for returning custom or existing C# objects from the cmdlet to the variable assignment (e.g. [PowerShell] $x = Do-Something, where [C#] WriteObject(Output) would be returned to [PowerShell] $x).

WriteInformation (new in PowerShell 5) is the new way to write to the output stream, Write-Output now redirects to the Information stream.